# Vite, MSW and basename

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mocking, vite, msw

I've configured Vite to work with MSW to intercept my requests, so far no issues with this. The `mockServiceWorker.js` file in inside public folder. However, i needed to add a property in my `vite.config.ts` named base:

```
vite.config.ts

export default defineConfig({
  base: '/kiosk',
  ...other configs...
```

With this, I also added the necessary property on `package.json`:

```
package.json

"homepage": "/kiosk",
...other configs...
```

This has broken the MSW functionality, and it doesn't intercept any request.

This is what i currently have in my MSW initializer.

```
import { StartOptions } from 'msw/browser';

export const enableMocking = async () => {
  if (!import.meta.env.DEV) return;

  const { worker } = await import('./browser');
  return worker.start(workerStartOptions);
};

const workerStartOptions: StartOptions = {
  serviceWorker: {
    url: '/kiosk/mockServiceWorker.js'
  },
};
```

And is not intercepting any request, while getting this message on the console:
`[MSW] Cannot intercept requests on this page because it's outside of the worker's scope ("http://localhost:3000/kiosk/"). If you wish to mock API requests on this page, you must resolve this scope issue.

- (Recommended) Register the worker at the root level ("/") of your application.
- Set the "Service-Worker-Allowed" response header to allow out-of-scope workers.`

Any solutions to get MSW to work with base paths?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well with Vite and MSW, and ran this:

```
npx msw init /
```

Seemed to fix it for me.

Although I'm not totally happy with the mockServiceWorker.js file being in my root project directory.

There is a possibility of adding the 'Service-Worker-Allowed' header to the handlers might work.

https://mswjs.io/docs/recipes/custom-worker-script-location/#option-2-service-worker-allowed-response-header